# SME server install from USB crashes with "IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system"

Tags: install, usb, sme-server

I managed to make my 8.0GB USB flash drive boot the current SME Server 8 beta ISO image. The installation program starts when I boot from USB, and configuration of install options worked fine.

After pressing "Install now", the installation starts, then ends with a python exception error:

> IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

I tried it twice and got the same error. What does this mean, and how should I alleviate this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your flash drive is NOT in NTFS filesystem as it is not supported.
For best results, format in ext3 filesystem. FAT32 would also go, but is not that efficient when it comes to speed and performance. Good luck.